# What is the best way to save login details for a custom CMS admin panel?

Tags: php, database, security, content-management-system, administrator

I'm working on a pretty basic CMS for some friends of mine. I made a database for the articles, users and other entities the CMS is going to need.

And of course, it will need an administrator account for loging into the admin panel.
But I don't know what the safest way for keeping administrator details is. Is it safe to store them with the general users, or should I make a special table for them?

I'm not sure if this is the safest way to keep these important details. So do any of you think I should forget about the database after all, and use another secure way of keeping this data?

Thanks,
-Robin

Comment: Sure, you can store them in the same table. You'll have to mark them as admins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the passwords are stored safely (salted hashes if you are storing passwords), there is no need to treat an administrator differently from a regular user. An administrator simply has more rights that are defined in the users table (like for example a user level or a super-user status) or a separate role table.

Comment: So I just added a permission column to the users. If the user is an admin they are allowed to log in the admin panel.

Comment: Oops, I didn't expect enter would post the comment. But to continue my post. This admin panel is much like wp-admin in wordpress and administrator in joomla. So I was wondering if this was a secure way to save the admin accounts in my CMS.

Comment: @CrispyGMR It seems a very good way to me and it's easy to implement with what you already have.